# What version of SSL and TLS does Wakanda build 11.197492 use?

Tags: ssl, wakanda

My Wakanda build 11.197492 app is getting SSL errors:

SSL internal error : error:1408A10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:wrong version number
SSL internal error : error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher

What version of SSL, and what ciphers does Wakanda build 11.197492 use?

Comment: The question is more what old client do you use that still sends an SSLv3 handshake?

Comment: I now see that Chrome is reporting:

The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, RSA, and AES_128_GCM.

RSA key exchange is obsolete. Enable an ECDHE-based cipher suite.

So the key exchange is using RSA. Will RSA become so obsolete that it will not be allowed at some point?

Comment: Since a few years the preferred ciphers are (EC)DHE based as they provide perfect forward secrecy (even if someone gains access to the server private key old recorded communication can not be decrypted). In TLS 1.3 there even is no longer an RSA based cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Because Chrome displays the information I needed this issue is closed.

The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, RSA, and AES_128_GCM. RSA key exchange is obsolete. Enable an ECDHE-based cipher suite.